# How to implement complex Ingress path based routing in kubernetese?

Tags: cloud, kubernetes-ingress

We are deploying a helm chart on kubernetese that eventually deploys custom docker image created from tomcat base image, this custom docker image contains 2 war files as **frontendui.war** which is an **angular app** & **backendapi.war** which is a **spring boot rest api**. Before deploying a pod, we rename the war files to enable **context path** as, for example, **customer1#prod#frontendui.war** & **customer1#prod#backendapi.war**

When we try to access these applications vis ingress, it simply unable to launch login screen which is landing page of our application.[It tries to load static resources directly from https://clm.domain/frontendui/*.js instead of https://clm.domain/customer1/prod/frontendui/runtime.js].

I'm looking for a path based routing where, we can have multiple namespaces for customers. For Example, the access urls can be, https://clm.domain/customer1/test/frontendu **or** https://clm.domain/customer1/prod/frontendui **or** https://clm.domain/customer2/test/frontendui, etc. Here is the ingress routes file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress-routes-{{ .Values.namespace }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.{{ .Values.domain }}"
      secretName: domain-certs-secret
  rules:
  - host: clm.{{ .Values.domain }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /{{ .Values.customer.name }}/{{ .Values.customer.environment }}/(frontendui/.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port:
              number: 8181
      - path: /{{ .Values.customer.name }}/{{ .Values.customer.environment }}/(backendapi/.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port:
              number: 8181
```

The question is, How can this be implemented ? PS : We don't want to go for **subdomain based routing** per customer. It would be great to have pointers to try & fix this, any guidance is much appreciated Thanks!